# Square matrix $\|Ax-Ay\|\le \|x-y\|$

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Could you give me an example of a square matrix $A\in \mathcal{M}_{2 \times 2}$ or $\mathcal{M}_{3 \times 3}$ for which we have $\|Ax-Ay\|\le \|x-y\|$, $ \ \ x, y \in \{0, e_1, . . . , e_n\}, \ \ e_1, . . . , e_n$ - canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm, but $\|Az\| > \|z\|$ for a certain vector $z$?

I think $A =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \frac{1}{3}  \\
0 & 1  \end{array} \right) $ will be good for the first case, but I have problem for the case where matrix has degree $3$.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't $Ae_1 = e_1+2e_2$, so $\|Ae_1\| = \sqrt5$?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I didn't notice. What if we take $0$ instead of $2$?

Comment: Now you have the same problem with $e_2$ ! The best case scenario is for every column vector to be a unit vector. If they're all mutually orthogonal, then the matrix is orthogonal, and so $\|Ax\| = \|x\|$ for all $x$. What happens if the columns are *not* mutually orthogonal?

Comment: I don't know. Whatever I do I get either $||Ax-Ay||\le ||x-y||$ or $||Ax||>0$. I don't know how to link those two.

Comment: Play around with some $2\times 2$ matrices whose column vectors are both unit vectors. Then you should see how to generalize to $3\times 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note*: My original answer contained an error; correcting the error led to this simpler solution. Most of the comments below refer to the original answer.

You can project onto the subspace of vectors with constant entries, using a matrix with constant entries. Then $Ae_i$ is the same for all $e_i$, so the left-hand side of the desired inequality is $0$ unless one of $x$, $y$ is $0$, in which case the inequality is fulfilled if you take less than $\sqrt n$ times the orthogonal projection. On the other hand, you can make $\lVert Az\rVert/\lvert z\rVert$ anything from $1$ to $\sqrt n$ for $z$ a vector with constant entries by using the corresponding multiple of the orthogonal projection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me why you multiply the matrices in this way?

Comment: @Sandy: This is an orthogonal transformation, $A=B^\top DB$, where $B$ in this case is symmetric and thus $B=B^\top$. The orthogonal matrix $B=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}$ transforms to the basis $\{e_1+e_2,e_1-e_2\}$, then the diagonal matrix $D=\pmatrix{0\\&\sqrt2}$ performs the desired scaling, and then $B^\top$ transforms back.

Comment: I've tried similar transformation with scaling by $\sqrt{3}$ but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sandy: Yes, that confirms what I wrote, since $\sqrt3\gt\sqrt2$.

Comment: Right:) Could you tell me what to do for matrices $3 \times 3$?

Comment: @Sandy: How about adding a zero row and column?

Comment: I've got one more question. I'vce just tried $\frac1{\sqrt2}\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}$ and it doesn't work for $||Ae_1-Ae_2||\le ||e_1-e_2||$. I get $||Ae_1-Ae_2|| =||[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ]-[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]|| =2$ and $||[0,1]-[1,0]|| = \sqrt{2}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Sandy: I'm sorry, you weren't doing anything wrong; I had the $0$ and $\sqrt2$ swapped in the diagonal matrix. If you correct that, you get a matrix with constant entries; I've replaced the answer with one that avoids the detour and just directly uses such a constant matrix to project onto the subspace of constant vectors.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What should this matrix look like?

Comment: Given an arbitrary vector $v$ not in $U$, we can project it onto $U$ by $v_{\| U} = \frac{\langle v , u \rangle}{\langle u , u \rangle} u$. How can we construct its matrix?

Comment: @Sandy: I'm not sure I understand the question. I wrote that it's a matrix with constant entries; that doesn't leave anything to construct. All you need is the constant value $c$ of the entries, and you can get the admissible interval for that by requiring that $\lVert Ae_i\rVert=c\sqrt n\le1$ and $\lVert Az\rVert/\lVert z\rVert=cn\gt1$.

Comment: So for matrix $2 \times 2$ I could take $0,7$ and for $3 \times 3$ we can take $0,5$, right. I'm sorry to bother you, but could you tell me once again why this works?

Comment: @Sandy: We seem to be talking past each other. I don't understand what you mean by "taking $0,7$". What I mean by a matrix with constant entries $c$ is the matrix

$$
\pmatrix{c&c\\c&c}\;.
$$

Comment: Yes, and $c\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \ \ c>\frac{1}{n}, \ \ n=2,3$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sandy: Yes, that's correct, though I'm not sure why you added $n=2,3$; those inequalities hold for general $n$.

Comment: I know. It's just that in the question I mentioned only those. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sandy: Ah, now I see what $0,7$ and $0,5$ was about. $\TeX$ is anglo-centric; it interprets periods as decimal periods and commas as punctuation, not as decimal commas, so you get bad spacing when you try to use the comma as a decimal comma. I see now that you meant $0.7$ and $0.5$. Yes, you can use those values.